# How to call latex located in docker?

Tags: docker, latex, tex-live

Is it possible to pull texlive image in docker (e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/texlive/texlive) and use it from my computer instead of installing texlive on my computer?

I like the idea using containers instead of installing software.

Comment: (IMHO running `brew install texlive` once and then running `latex some-file` directly is much better than the long-winded `docker run` command you've gotten as a correct answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work something like

```
sudo docker run -i --rm --name latex -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest pdflatex essay.tex
```

Taken from https://nico.dorfbrunnen.eu/de/posts/2020/docker-latex/ (german)

Check wiki page for docker images: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive/-/wikis/home

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX's full distribution is too large. I recommend using TinyTeX and then add packages as needed. This should work:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install perl wget -y  
wget -qO- "https://yihui.org/tinytex/install-bin-unix.sh" | sh 
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux"
```

From here, run bash in your container, compile your latex file, and check what packages are missing. For example, you may get a message such as `` ! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found. `` In this case, from inside a container run `tlmgr search --global --file "type1cm.sty"` which will output something like this:

```
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
type1cm:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty
```

then, run

```
tlmgr install type1cm
```

Repeat this process until you have all the packages you need. In my case also needed to add dvipng, required by Python’s matplotlib package:

```
apt-get install dvipng -y
```

(for some reason I needed to install it *after* TinyTeX).

The equivalent in a Dockerfile would be the following:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install perl wget -y  

# fetch TinyTeX installer and run it
RUN wget -qO- "https://yihui.org/tinytex/install-bin-unix.sh" | sh 

# add TinyTeX to PATH variable
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux"

# add needed packages and dvipng:
RUN tlmgr install type1cm
RUN apt-get install dvipng
```